# C++ vector of strings , lifetimes, and uninitialized values problem

Tags: c++, initialization, valgrind, lifetime

Cheers, I am trying to write me own shell. I am using CPP because I find it easy to play with `std::vector` and `std::string`. However, I think I have blown my own foot out with the lifetime of the variables, and I don't know where to start in order to save it. **Any help would be greatly appreciated since I don't know even know where to begin.**

Below is the starting loop code: I get the line of the user that was typed in, and then I proceed to parse it. To do I use two functions, which at the end return the whole tokenized string. Because inside there may exists ";", which separate commands, I want to create distinct vectors of strings, which I do by going over the string, and when a ";" is found, or we are at the end, I simply push to the vector holding the command so far.

```
void myshell_loop() {
    std::string userInput;

    while (1) {
        int pid;
        int status;
        // For the zombie processes
        while ((pid = waitpid(-1, &status, WNOHANG|WUNTRACED)) > 0) {}


        myshell_promt();
        std::getline(std::cin, userInput);
        if (userInput == "") { continue; }
        if (userInput == "exit") { break; }


        std::vector<std::string> strip_quotes = parsing::parseString(userInput);
        std::vector<std::string> tokens = parsing::tokenize(strip_quotes);
        // Now we have the complete token list, which however may contain ";"

        std::vector<std::string> seperated_jobs;
        std::vector<std::vector<std::string>> command_list;

        for(int i = 0; i < tokens.size();i++) {
            if (tokens[i] == ";" || i == tokens.size()-1) {
                if (i == tokens.size()-1 ) seperated_jobs.push_back(tokens[i]);
                command_list.push_back(seperated_jobs);
                seperated_jobs.clear();
            } else {
                seperated_jobs.push_back(tokens[i]);                
            }
        }

        std::vector<std::string> token;
        std::string command_rebuilt = "";
        for(int i = 0; i < command_list.size();i++) {
            token =  command_list[i];
            // Add null termination
            token.push_back("\0");
            
            for(int j = 0; j < token.size(); j++) {
                command_rebuilt += " " + token[i];
            }

            for(int i = 0; i < token.size(); i++) {
                std::cout << "token[" << i << "]: " << token[i] << std::endl;
            }
            class job* job = mysh_parse_command(token, command_rebuilt);
            int status = mysh_launch_job(job);
            delete job;
            command_rebuilt = "";
        }
    }
}

int main() {

    myshell_init();
    myshell_loop();

    delete shell;
    return 0;
}
```

Now for the parse command part: I firstly call mysh_parse_command, which creates a job (that consist of many individual processes). When a "|" is found, I call the mysh_parse_cmd_segment which returns a object of process.

```
class job* mysh_parse_command(std::vector<std::string> tcl, std::string command_given) {
    // A job is a series of processes
    // which are connected as a linked list, job has access to 
    class process* root = NULL, *piped = NULL;

    // Here have the individual commands/processes
    std::vector<std::string> cmd;

    for(int i = 0; i < tcl.size(); i++) {
        // If we get a piping operator, we should split
        // and create a process
        if ( (tcl[i] == "|" ) || tcl[i] == "\0") {
            class process* new_proc = mysh_parse_cmd_segment(cmd);
            // This is the very first process
            if (root == NULL) {
                root = new_proc;
                piped = root;
            } else {
                // Set old process to have its new as
                // the newly created
                piped->set_next(new_proc);
                piped = new_proc;
            }
            // Start from scratch again, reseting the cmd
            cmd.clear();
        } else {
            // If we don't get a pipe, we push to the current cmd
            cmd.push_back(tcl[i]);
        }
    }

    job* ret = new job();

    // Doesn't have a group id yet
    ret->pgid = -1;

    // And will be executed 
    ret->mode = mode;

    ret->command = command_given;

    // And set the root of the job to be from the root process
    ret->set_root(root);

    return ret;
}

class process* mysh_parse_cmd_segment(std::vector<std::string> tcl) {

    // tcl is NULL terminated
    class process* test = new process();
    int glob_count = 0, position = 0;
    char* input_path = NULL;
    char* output_path = NULL;
    test->append = false;

    if (tcl[0] == "createalias") {
        // if the command that was given was "createalias"
        // we have a special treatment:
        // First parameter parsed is the alias name-key
        // Everything after that must be inside quotes
        // and no other processing will take place

        // tcl[0] -> "createalias" , tcl[1] -> key , tcl[2] -> values
        
        commands.push_back(tcl[0].c_str());
        if (tcl[1] == "\0" || tcl[2] == "\0") {
            fprintf(stderr, "mysh: createalias needs more parameters");
        } else {   
            commands.push_back(tcl[1].c_str());
            commands.push_back(tcl[2].c_str());

            std::cout << "key: " << commands[1] << std::endl;
            std::cout << "values: " << commands[2] << std::endl;
            if (parsing::isDoubleQuoted(tcl[2]) != true) {
                fprintf(stderr, "mysh: createalias: parameters should be contained in double quotes\n");
                fprintf(stderr, "createalias <KEY> \" <command> \" ");
            }
        }

    } else {
        for(int i = 0 ; i < tcl.size();++i) {
            // If it's a redirection , save the input and output paths, but don't put into the
            // command

            if (tcl[i] == ">" || tcl[i] == "<" || tcl[i] == ">>") {
                if (tcl[i] == ">") {
                    output_path = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char)*(tcl[i+1].length() + 1));
                    strcpy(output_path, tcl[i+1].c_str() );
                    i++;
                    std::cout << output_path << std::endl;
                    test->append = false;
                } else if (tcl[i] == "<") {
                    input_path = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char)*(tcl[i+1].length() + 1));
                    strcpy(input_path, tcl[i+1].c_str() );
                    i++;
                    std::cout << input_path << std::endl;
                } else if (tcl[i] == ">>") {
                    output_path = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char)*(tcl[i+1].length() + 1));
                    strcpy(input_path, tcl[i+1].c_str() );
                    i++;
                    std::cout << output_path << std::endl;
                    test->append = true;
                }
            } else {
                // If there isn't a redirection symbol we take it a part of the command's parameters
                commands.push_back(tcl[i].c_str());
            }
        }
    }

    printf("We have created the following command: \n");
    std::cout << "-----\n";
    print(commands);
    std::cout << "-----\n";

    test->input_path = input_path;
    test->output_path = output_path;
    test->pid = -1;
    test->argc = commands.size() + 1;
    test->argv = (char**) malloc(sizeof(char*) * (commands.size()+1) );
    test->set_next(NULL);
    
    for(int i = 0; i < commands.size();i++) {
        test->argv[i] = strdup(commands[i]);
    }
    test->argv[commands.size()] = NULL;

    printf("> -> %s\n",  output_path);
    printf("< -> %s\n", input_path);

    // Get the command/process type from the shell
    // Because it might be aliased, and the alias lives inside the shell

    shell->set_command_type(test->argv[0], test);

    test->command = strdup(test->argv[0]);
    return test;
}
```

Below I list the classes used:

```
class process {
    public:
        char *command;
        int argc;
        char **argv;
        char *input_path;
        char *output_path;
        bool append;
        pid_t pid;
        int type;
        int status;
        class process *next;
        // Simple destructor freeing the process malloced const char*s
        ~process() {
            free(command);

            printf("Deleting process\n");
            free(input_path);
            free(output_path);
            for(int i = 0; i < argc; i++)
                free(argv[i]);
            
            free(argv);
        }
        int get_process_type() { return this->type; }
        int get_process_status() { return this->status; }
        void set_process_status( int status ) { this->status = status; } 
        void set_next(class process* proc) { this->next = proc; }
        class process* get_next_process() { return this->next; }
        void set_pid(pid_t pid) { this->pid = pid; }
        int get_pid() { return this->pid; }
};

class job {
    public:
        int id;
        class process *root;
        std::string command;
        pid_t pgid;
        int mode;

        void set_root(struct process* new_root) {
            this->root = new_root;
        }

        int get_pgid() { return pgid; }
        void set_pgid(int pgid) { this->pgid = pgid; }
        int get_root_process_type() { return root->get_process_type(); }
        void set_job_id(int new_id ) { this->id = new_id; }
        ~job() {
            std::cout << "At job outting:" << std::endl;
            struct process *proc, *temp;
            for(proc = root; proc != NULL;) {
                temp = proc->next;
                delete proc;
                proc = temp;
            }
        }
};

class shell_info {
    public:
        std::vector<job*> jobs_running;
        std::map<std::string , std::string> alias;

        char cur_dir[PW_DIR_BUFFER];
        char cur_user[CUR_USER_BUFFER];
        char pw_dir[PW_DIR_BUFFER];

        void set_command_type(char* command, class process* p) {
            // Now check if it's a aliased command
            std::string key = command;
            std::map<std::string,std::string>::iterator it;
            it = alias.find(key);
            if (it != alias.end()) {
                p->type = COMMAND_ALIAS;
            } else {
                if (strcmp(command, "cd") == 0) {
                    p->type = COMMAND_CD;
                } else if (strcmp(command, "createalias") == 0) {
                    p->type = COMMAND_CREATEALIAS;
                } else if (strcmp(command, "destroyalias") == 0) {
                    p->type = COMMAND_DESTROYALIAS;
                } else {
                    p->type = COMMAND_EXTERNAL;
                }
            }
        }

        int mysh_create_alias(char** argv, int argc) {
            assert(strcmp(argv[0], "createalias") == 0);
            if ( argc != 4 ) { fprintf(stderr, "createalias: 2 arguments only"); return -1;}
            // Insert to map holding the aliases: <string> -> <string>
            // e.g. if "createalias myhome "cd /home/something" : <cd> -> <"home/something">
            std::string key = argv[1];
            std::string value = argv[2];
            
            // Search if it is inside the aliases
            std::map<std::string,std::string>::iterator it;
            it = alias.find(key);

            // If not found, insert it to the aliases
            if (it == alias.end())
                alias.insert(std::pair<std::string,std::string>(key,value));
            else {
            // Dispay error and do not change the value
                fprintf(stderr, "mysh: alias error: there already exists a alias for: %s\n", argv[1]);
            }
            return mysh_show_aliases();
        }

        int mysh_delete_alias(char** argv, int argc) {
            assert(strcmp(argv[0], "destroyalias") == 0);
            if ( argc != 3 ) { fprintf(stderr, "destroyalias: 1 argument only"); return -1;}
            std::map<std::string,std::string>::iterator it;
            std::string key = argv[1];
            int res = alias.erase(key);
            if (res == 0) {
                fprintf(stderr, "mysh: alias error: could not perform alias destruction for: %s\n", argv[1]);
                return -1;
            } else {
                fprintf(stdout, "successfully deleted alias with key: %s\n", argv[1]);
            }
            mysh_show_aliases();
            return 0;
        }

        int mysh_show_aliases() {
            std::map<std::string,std::string>::iterator it;
            for (it=alias.begin(); it!=alias.end(); ++it)
                std::cout << it->first << " => " << it->second << '\n';
            return 1;
        }

        int mysh_execute_alias(char** argv, int argc) {
            std::string command_to_be_executed = alias.find(argv[0])->second;
            // Just remove the double quotes in the start and at the end
            command_to_be_executed.erase(command_to_be_executed.begin());
            command_to_be_executed.erase(command_to_be_executed.end()-1);
            std::cout << "Command retrieved: " << command_to_be_executed << "\n";
            
            // Repeat the same code from the main loop
            std::vector<std::string> strip_quotes = parsing::parseString(command_to_be_executed);
            std::vector<std::string> tokens = parsing::tokenize(strip_quotes);

            // Now we have the complete token list, which however may contain ";"
            std::vector<std::string> seperated_jobs;
            std::vector<std::vector<std::string>> command_list;

            for(int i = 0; i < tokens.size();i++) {
                if (tokens[i] == ";" || i == tokens.size()-1) {
                    if (i == tokens.size()-1 ) seperated_jobs.push_back(tokens[i]);
                    command_list.push_back(seperated_jobs);
                    seperated_jobs.clear();
                } else {
                    seperated_jobs.push_back(tokens[i]);                
                }
            }
            // seperated_jobs -> A vector containing many individual jobs
            // command_list   -> A job, a.k.a. a vector of many processes
            std::vector<std::string> token;
            for(int i = 0; i < command_list.size();i++) {
                token = command_list[i];
                // Add null termination
                token.push_back("\0");
                std::string command_rebuilt = "";
                for(int j = 0; j < token.size(); j++) {
                    command_rebuilt += " " + token[i];
                }

                for(int i = 0; i < token.size(); i++) {
                    std::cout << "token[" << i << "]: " << token[i] << std::endl;
                }
                class job* job = mysh_parse_command(token, command_rebuilt);
                int status = mysh_launch_job(job);
                delete job;
            }
            
            return 0;
        }
        
        int mysh_execute_builtin(class process* p){
            int status = 1;
            switch (p->type) {
                case COMMAND_CREATEALIAS:
                    mysh_create_alias(p->argv, p->argc);
                    break;
                case COMMAND_DESTROYALIAS:
                    mysh_delete_alias(p->argv, p->argc);
                    break;
                case COMMAND_ALIAS:
                    mysh_execute_alias(p->argv, p->argc);
                    break;
                default:
                    status = 0;
                    break;
            }

            return status;
        }
        int get_next_job_id() {
            for(int i = 1; i <= 20; i++) {
                if (this->jobs_running[i] == NULL) {
                    return i;
                }
            }
            return -1;
        }

        int insert_new_job( class job* job_to_insert ) {
            int id = this->get_next_job_id();
            // Job vector if full
            if (id < 0) { return -1 ; } 
            // Else, we found a spare place to place it

            // Set the job's id to the acquired one
            // And place it into the the shell

            job_to_insert->set_job_id(id);
            set_job(id, job_to_insert);

            return id;
        }

        void set_job(const int id, class job* job_to_insert ) {
            jobs_running[id] = job_to_insert;
        }

        int release_job(int id) {
            if (id > 20 || this->jobs_running[id] == NULL)
                return -1;
            
            struct job* job = this->jobs_running[id];
            return 0;
        }
        int remove_job(int id) {
            if (id > 20 || this->jobs_running[id] == NULL)
                return -1;

            release_job(id);
            this->jobs_running[id] = NULL;

            return 0;
        }

};
```

There's more code, .e.g. `launch_job` which executes each process as it should, but I think something is already wrong with the code that I have written above. Ran with valgrind for an command like: `createalias kt "ls" ; kt ; kt ; kt ; kt`, I get the following errors:

```
==26255== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==26255==    at 0x49990EC: std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::_M_replace(unsigned long, unsigned long, char const*, unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.28)
==26255==    by 0x113CDB: myshell_loop() (in )
==26255==    by 0x113EBC: main (in )
==26255== 
==26255== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==26255==    at 0x4999119: std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::_M_replace(unsigned long, unsigned long, char const*, unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.28)
==26255==    by 0x113CDB: myshell_loop() (in )
==26255==    by 0x113EBC: main (in )
==26255== 
==26255== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==26255==    at 0x4999140: std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::_M_replace(unsigned long, unsigned long, char const*, unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.28)
==26255==    by 0x113CDB: myshell_loop() (in )
==26255==    by 0x113EBC: main (in )
==26255== 
==26255== Use of uninitialised value of size 8
==26255==    at 0x4999196: std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::_M_replace(unsigned long, unsigned long, char const*, unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.28)
==26255==    by 0x113CDB: myshell_loop() (in )
==26255==    by 0x113EBC: main ()
==26255==
```

as well as some more. Any hints on what could be going wrong ? Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: Get rid of most, if not all of the pointers and pointer usage.   A modern C++ program shouldn't need to be written with `new` and `delete` all over the place like this.  Then use `std::list<process>` instead of what you have now.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Thanks for the comment! What pointers do your recommend getting rid of? Changing the functions to return objects instead of pointers to objects? Because these are the only ones I use `new` for. Thanks again!!

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I also play with pointers since I need a const char* to execute `exec` when playing with the process execution. That being said, these pointers should go too?

Comment: `command_rebuilt += " " + token[i];` in a loop on `j`!

Comment: @dalfaB Wow! I think that was the problem! I am kind of ashamed about it now. Thanks a ton! I will keep the question open, for more suggestions about how I can  refactor my code to be cleaner, since it is mess! Thanks again!!

Comment: @a_confused_programmer You can get a `const char*` from a `std::string` with the `c_str` method. Use strings and vectors thoughout your code, where you need a pointer for some legacy function get the pointer from your string or vector **at the point where you call the legacy function**. That's the simple way to organise your code.